# OS locale support for use in Python

Tags: python, locale

The following Python code works on my Windows machine (Python 2.5.4), but doesn't on my Debian machine (Python 2.5.0). I'm guessing it's OS dependent.

```
import locale
locale.setlocale( locale.LC_ALL, 'English_United States.1252' )
```

I receive the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/locale.py", line 476, in setlocale
    return _setlocale(category, locale)
locale.Error: unsupported locale setting
```

Questions:

- Is it OS dependent?
- How can I find the supported locale
  list within Python?
- How can I match between Windows
  locales and Debian locales?

Comment: do you have to hardcode the locale? setlocale(LC_ALL, "") will load the locale defined by the environment.

Answer (score 22):

It is OS dependent.

To get the list of local available you can use `locale -a` in a shell

I think the local you want is something like [`Windows-1252`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252)

Comment: there's no locale -a in windows

Answer (score 9):

try

```
apt-get install locales-all
```

for me it works like a charm

Comment: This is also helpful if one wants to configure locales selectively: http://tlug.dnho.net/node/237

Comment: If your want to be a bit more selective, you can install one of the language-pack-* packages, e.g. language-pack-de.

Comment: do you know what the yum equivocation is? yum install locales-all doesnt work.

Answer (score 8):

Look inside the `locale.locale_alias` dictionary.

```
>>> import locale
>>> len(locale.locale_alias)
789
>>> locale.locale_alias.keys()[:5]
['ko_kr.euc', 'is_is', 'ja_jp.mscode', 'kw_gb@euro', 'yi_us.cp1255']
>>>
```

(In my 2.6.2 installation there are 789 locale names.)

Comment: Actually, the locales defined in the alias dictionary are not necessarily supported.

Comment: I tried a variation of this which was list(set(locale.locale_alias.values()) (values instead of keys because I want the real values, and convert to set and list again to retain only unique values).  However there's another problem, as raised here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1728376/python-get-a-list-of-all-the-encodings-python-can-encode-to/1736533#1736533): are there locales which don't have aliases, and won't be in the alias dictionary at all?

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu Precise type

sudo locale-gen en_US